# What programming languages are required for the ServiceM8 API?

Tags: servicem8

I am currently on the look out for a backend web developer but before I search for one I need to know the programming languages to find the right person.

ServiceM8's customer service team told me Python for web and Swift for app. Can I confirm this? You can see their API doc here: https://developer.servicem8.com/docs/getting-started

I am not sure what the difference is here (I know they are both programming languages, but not sure when they'd be used).

Thanks!
Dmitri.

Comment: REST APIs are language agnostic, all you need is to be able to make HTTP requests. Are you familiar with HTTP?

Comment: @alter_igel unfortunately I am not! I am just not sure what I should be looking for when looking for a web developer to see if they can connect to the ServiceM8 API. Any help would be great!